# R - Data Frame Forward and Backward Fill

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

I have a data frame and am trying to fill the missing values with the previous and next values in the data frame. I used the following code, but it did not fill and returns missing values still. I tried 2 different variations, but both do not work. Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

**Data frame:** 'oil.csv'

```
date    dcoilwtico
1/1/13  
1/2/13  93.14
1/3/13  92.97
1/4/13  93.12
1/7/13  93.2
1/8/13  93.21
1/9/13  93.08
1/10/13 93.81
1/11/13 93.6
1/14/13 94.27
1/15/13 93.26
1/16/13 94.28
1/17/13 95.49
1/18/13 95.61
1/21/13 
1/22/13 96.09
```

**dput(oil_df)**:

```
structure(list(date = c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-02", "2013-01-03", 
"2013-01-04", "2013-01-07", "2013-01-08", "2013-01-09", "2013-01-10", 
"2013-01-11", "2013-01-14", "2013-01-15", "2013-01-16", "2013-01-17", 
"2013-01-18", "2013-01-21", "2013-01-22", "2013-01-23", "2013-01-24", 
"2013-01-25", "2013-01-28", "2013-01-29", "2013-01-30", "2013-01-31", 
"2013-02-01", "2013-02-04", "2013-02-05", "2013-02-06", "2013-02-07", 
"2013-02-08", "2013-02-11", "2013-02-12", "2013-02-13", "2013-02-14", 
"2013-02-15", "2013-02-18", "2013-02-19", "2013-02-20", "2013-02-21", 
"2013-02-22", "2013-02-25", "2013-02-26", "2013-02-27", "2013-02-28", 
"2013-03-01", "2013-03-04", "2013-03-05", "2013-03-06", "2013-03-07", 
"2013-03-08", "2013-03-11", "2013-03-12", "2013-03-13", "2013-03-14", 
"2013-03-15", "2013-03-18", "2013-03-19", "2013-03-20", "2013-03-21", 
"2013-03-22", "2013-03-25", "2013-03-26", "2013-03-27", "2013-03-28", 
"2013-03-29", "2013-04-01", "2013-04-02", "2013-04-03", "2013-04-04", 
"2013-04-05", "2013-04-08", "2013-04-09", "2013-04-10", "2013-04-11", 
"2013-04-12", "2013-04-15", "2013-04-16", "2013-04-17", "2013-04-18", 
"2013-04-19", "2013-04-22", "2013-04-23", "2013-04-24", "2013-04-25", 
"2013-04-26", "2013-04-29", "2013-04-30", "2013-05-01", "2013-05-02", 
"2013-05-03", "2013-05-06", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-08", "2013-05-09", 
"2013-05-10", "2013-05-13", "2013-05-14", "2013-05-15", "2013-05-16", 
"2013-05-17", "2013-05-20", "2013-05-21", "2013-05-22", "2013-05-23", 
"2013-05-24", "2013-05-27", "2013-05-28", "2013-05-29", "2013-05-30", 
"2013-05-31", "2013-06-03", "2013-06-04", "2013-06-05", "2013-06-06", 
"2013-06-07", "2013-06-10", "2013-06-11", "2013-06-12", "2013-06-13", 
"2013-06-14", "2013-06-17", "2013-06-18", "2013-06-19", "2013-06-20", 
"2013-06-21", "2013-06-24", "2013-06-25", "2013-06-26", "2013-06-27", 
"2013-06-28", "2013-07-01", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-03", "2013-07-04", 
"2013-07-05", "2013-07-08", "2013-07-09", "2013-07-10", "2013-07-11", 
"2013-07-12", "2013-07-15", "2013-07-16", "2013-07-17", "2013-07-18", 
"2013-07-19", "2013-07-22", "2013-07-23", "2013-07-24", "2013-07-25", 
"2013-07-26", "2013-07-29", "2013-07-30", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-01", 
"2013-08-02", "2013-08-05", "2013-08-06", "2013-08-07", "2013-08-08", 
"2013-08-09", "2013-08-12", "2013-08-13", "2013-08-14", "2013-08-15", 
"2013-08-16", "2013-08-19", "2013-08-20", "2013-08-21", "2013-08-22", 
"2013-08-23", "2013-08-26", "2013-08-27", "2013-08-28", "2013-08-29", 
"2013-08-30", "2013-09-02", "2013-09-03", "2013-09-04", "2013-09-05", 
"2013-09-06", "2013-09-09", "2013-09-10", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-12", 
"2013-09-13", "2013-09-16", "2013-09-17", "2013-09-18", "2013-09-19", 
"2013-09-20", "2013-09-23", "2013-09-24", "2013-09-25", "2013-09-26", 
"2013-09-27", "2013-09-30", "2013-10-01", "2013-10-02", "2013-10-03", 
"2013-10-04", "2013-10-07", "2013-10-08", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-10", 
"2013-10-11", "2013-10-14", "2013-10-15", "2013-10-16", "2013-10-17", 
"2013-10-18", "2013-10-21", "2013-10-22", "2013-10-23", "2013-10-24", 
"2013-10-25", "2013-10-28", "2013-10-29", "2013-10-30", "2013-10-31", 
"2013-11-01", "2013-11-04", "2013-11-05", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-07", 
"2013-11-08", "2013-11-11", "2013-11-12", "2013-11-13", "2013-11-14", 
"2013-11-15", "2013-11-18", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-20", "2013-11-21", 
"2013-11-22", "2013-11-25", "2013-11-26", "2013-11-27", "2013-11-28", 
"2013-11-29", "2013-12-02", "2013-12-03", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-05", 
"2013-12-06", "2013-12-09", "2013-12-10", "2013-12-11", "2013-12-12", 
"2013-12-13", "2013-12-16", "2013-12-17", "2013-12-18", "2013-12-19", 
"2013-12-20", "2013-12-23", "2013-12-24", "2013-12-25", "2013-12-26", 
"2013-12-27", "2013-12-30", "2013-12-31", "2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", 
"2014-01-03", "2014-01-06", "2014-01-07", "2014-01-08", "2014-01-09", 
"2014-01-10", "2014-01-13", "2014-01-14", "2014-01-15", "2014-01-16", 
"2014-01-17", "2014-01-20", "2014-01-21", "2014-01-22", "2014-01-23", 
"2014-01-24", "2014-01-27", "2014-01-28", "2014-01-29", "2014-01-30", 
"2014-01-31", "2014-02-03", "2014-02-04", "2014-02-05", "2014-02-06", 
"2014-02-07", "2014-02-10", "2014-02-11", "2014-02-12", "2014-02-13", 
"2014-02-14", "2014-02-17", "2014-02-18", "2014-02-19", "2014-02-20", 
"2014-02-21", "2014-02-24", "2014-02-25", "2014-02-26", "2014-02-27", 
"2014-02-28", "2014-03-03", "2014-03-04", "2014-03-05", "2014-03-06", 
"2014-03-07", "2014-03-10", "2014-03-11", "2014-03-12", "2014-03-13", 
"2014-03-14", "2014-03-17", "2014-03-18", "2014-03-19", "2014-03-20", 
"2014-03-21", "2014-03-24", "2014-03-25", "2014-03-26", "2014-03-27", 
"2014-03-28", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-01", "2014-04-02", "2014-04-03", 
"2014-04-04", "2014-04-07", "2014-04-08", "2014-04-09", "2014-04-10", 
"2014-04-11", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-15", "2014-04-16", "2014-04-17", 
"2014-04-18", "2014-04-21", "2014-04-22", "2014-04-23", "2014-04-24", 
"2014-04-25", "2014-04-28", "2014-04-29", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-01", 
"2014-05-02", "2014-05-05", "2014-05-06", "2014-05-07", "2014-05-08", 
"2014-05-09", "2014-05-12", "2014-05-13", "2014-05-14", "2014-05-15", 
"2014-05-16", "2014-05-19", "2014-05-20", "2014-05-21", "2014-05-22", 
"2014-05-23", "2014-05-26", "2014-05-27", "2014-05-28", "2014-05-29", 
"2014-05-30", "2014-06-02", "2014-06-03", "2014-06-04", "2014-06-05", 
"2014-06-06", "2014-06-09", "2014-06-10", "2014-06-11", "2014-06-12", 
"2014-06-13", "2014-06-16", "2014-06-17", "2014-06-18", "2014-06-19", 
"2014-06-20", "2014-06-23", "2014-06-24", "2014-06-25", "2014-06-26", 
"2014-06-27", "2014-06-30", "2014-07-01", "2014-07-02", "2014-07-03", 
"2014-07-04", "2014-07-07", "2014-07-08", "2014-07-09", "2014-07-10", 
"2014-07-11", "2014-07-14", "2014-07-15", "2014-07-16", "2014-07-17", 
"2014-07-18", "2014-07-21", "2014-07-22", "2014-07-23", "2014-07-24", 
"2014-07-25", "2014-07-28", "2014-07-29", "2014-07-30", "2014-07-31", 
"2014-08-01", "2014-08-04", "2014-08-05", "2014-08-06", "2014-08-07", 
"2014-08-08", "2014-08-11", "2014-08-12", "2014-08-13", "2014-08-14", 
"2014-08-15", "2014-08-18", "2014-08-19", "2014-08-20", "2014-08-21", 
"2014-08-22", "2014-08-25", "2014-08-26", "2014-08-27", "2014-08-28", 
"2014-08-29", "2014-09-01", "2014-09-02", "2014-09-03", "2014-09-04", 
"2014-09-05", "2014-09-08", "2014-09-09", "2014-09-10", "2014-09-11", 
"2014-09-12", "2014-09-15", "2014-09-16", "2014-09-17", "2014-09-18", 
"2014-09-19", "2014-09-22", "2014-09-23", "2014-09-24", "2014-09-25", 
"2014-09-26", "2014-09-29", "2014-09-30", "2014-10-01", "2014-10-02", 
"2014-10-03", "2014-10-06", "2014-10-07", "2014-10-08", "2014-10-09", 
"2014-10-10", "2014-10-13", "2014-10-14", "2014-10-15", "2014-10-16", 
"2014-10-17", "2014-10-20", "2014-10-21", "2014-10-22", "2014-10-23", 
"2014-10-24", "2014-10-27", "2014-10-28", "2014-10-29", "2014-10-30", 
"2014-10-31", "2014-11-03", "2014-11-04", "2014-11-05", "2014-11-06", 
"2014-11-07", "2014-11-10", "2014-11-11", "2014-11-12", "2014-11-13", 
"2014-11-14", "2014-11-17", "2014-11-18", "2014-11-19", "2014-11-20", 
"2014-11-21", "2014-11-24", "2014-11-25", "2014-11-26", "2014-11-27", 
"2014-11-28", "2014-12-01", "2014-12-02", "2014-12-03", "2014-12-04", 
"2014-12-05", "2014-12-08", "2014-12-09", "2014-12-10", "2014-12-11", 
"2014-12-12", "2014-12-15", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-17", "2014-12-18", 
"2014-12-19", "2014-12-22", "2014-12-23", "2014-12-24", "2014-12-25", 
"2014-12-26", "2014-12-29", "2014-12-30", "2014-12-31", "2015-01-01", 
"2015-01-02", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-08", 
"2015-01-09", "2015-01-12", "2015-01-13", "2015-01-14", "2015-01-15", 
"2015-01-16", "2015-01-19", "2015-01-20", "2015-01-21", "2015-01-22", 
"2015-01-23", "2015-01-26", "2015-01-27", "2015-01-28", "2015-01-29", 
"2015-01-30", "2015-02-02", "2015-02-03", "2015-02-04", "2015-02-05", 
"2015-02-06", "2015-02-09", "2015-02-10", "2015-02-11", "2015-02-12", 
"2015-02-13", "2015-02-16", "2015-02-17", "2015-02-18", "2015-02-19", 
"2015-02-20", "2015-02-23", "2015-02-24", "2015-02-25", "2015-02-26", 
"2015-02-27", "2015-03-02", "2015-03-03", "2015-03-04", "2015-03-05", 
"2015-03-06", "2015-03-09", "2015-03-10", "2015-03-11", "2015-03-12", 
"2015-03-13", "2015-03-16", "2015-03-17", "2015-03-18", "2015-03-19", 
"2015-03-20", "2015-03-23", "2015-03-24", "2015-03-25", "2015-03-26", 
"2015-03-27", "2015-03-30", "2015-03-31", "2015-04-01", "2015-04-02", 
"2015-04-03", "2015-04-06", "2015-04-07", "2015-04-08", "2015-04-09", 
"2015-04-10", "2015-04-13", "2015-04-14", "2015-04-15", "2015-04-16", 
"2015-04-17", "2015-04-20", "2015-04-21", "2015-04-22", "2015-04-23", 
"2015-04-24", "2015-04-27", "2015-04-28", "2015-04-29", "2015-04-30", 
"2015-05-01", "2015-05-04", "2015-05-05", "2015-05-06", "2015-05-07", 
"2015-05-08", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-12", "2015-05-13", "2015-05-14", 
"2015-05-15", "2015-05-18", "2015-05-19", "2015-05-20", "2015-05-21", 
"2015-05-22", "2015-05-25", "2015-05-26", "2015-05-27", "2015-05-28", 
"2015-05-29", "2015-06-01", "2015-06-02", "2015-06-03", "2015-06-04", 
"2015-06-05", "2015-06-08", "2015-06-09", "2015-06-10", "2015-06-11", 
"2015-06-12", "2015-06-15", "2015-06-16", "2015-06-17", "2015-06-18", 
"2015-06-19", "2015-06-22", "2015-06-23", "2015-06-24", "2015-06-25", 
"2015-06-26", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-30", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-02", 
"2015-07-03", "2015-07-06", "2015-07-07", "2015-07-08", "2015-07-09", 
"2015-07-10", "2015-07-13", "2015-07-14", "2015-07-15", "2015-07-16", 
"2015-07-17", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-23", 
"2015-07-24", "2015-07-27", "2015-07-28", "2015-07-29", "2015-07-30", 
"2015-07-31", "2015-08-03", "2015-08-04", "2015-08-05", "2015-08-06", 
"2015-08-07", "2015-08-10", "2015-08-11", "2015-08-12", "2015-08-13", 
"2015-08-14", "2015-08-17", "2015-08-18", "2015-08-19", "2015-08-20", 
"2015-08-21", "2015-08-24", "2015-08-25", "2015-08-26", "2015-08-27", 
"2015-08-28", "2015-08-31", "2015-09-01", "2015-09-02", "2015-09-03", 
"2015-09-04", "2015-09-07", "2015-09-08", "2015-09-09", "2015-09-10", 
"2015-09-11", "2015-09-14", "2015-09-15", "2015-09-16", "2015-09-17", 
"2015-09-18", "2015-09-21", "2015-09-22", "2015-09-23", "2015-09-24", 
"2015-09-25", "2015-09-28", "2015-09-29", "2015-09-30", "2015-10-01", 
"2015-10-02", "2015-10-05", "2015-10-06", "2015-10-07", "2015-10-08", 
"2015-10-09", "2015-10-12", "2015-10-13", "2015-10-14", "2015-10-15", 
"2015-10-16", "2015-10-19", "2015-10-20", "2015-10-21", "2015-10-22", 
"2015-10-23", "2015-10-26", "2015-10-27", "2015-10-28", "2015-10-29", 
"2015-10-30", "2015-11-02", "2015-11-03", "2015-11-04", "2015-11-05", 
"2015-11-06", "2015-11-09", "2015-11-10", "2015-11-11", "2015-11-12", 
"2015-11-13", "2015-11-16", "2015-11-17", "2015-11-18", "2015-11-19", 
"2015-11-20", "2015-11-23", "2015-11-24", "2015-11-25", "2015-11-26", 
"2015-11-27", "2015-11-30", "2015-12-01", "2015-12-02", "2015-12-03", 
"2015-12-04", "2015-12-07", "2015-12-08", "2015-12-09", "2015-12-10", 
"2015-12-11", "2015-12-14", "2015-12-15", "2015-12-16", "2015-12-17", 
"2015-12-18", "2015-12-21", "2015-12-22", "2015-12-23", "2015-12-24", 
"2015-12-25", "2015-12-28", "2015-12-29", "2015-12-30", "2015-12-31", 
"2016-01-01", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07", 
"2016-01-08", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-12", "2016-01-13", "2016-01-14", 
"2016-01-15", "2016-01-18", "2016-01-19", "2016-01-20", "2016-01-21", 
"2016-01-22", "2016-01-25", "2016-01-26", "2016-01-27", "2016-01-28", 
"2016-01-29", "2016-02-01", "2016-02-02", "2016-02-03", "2016-02-04", 
"2016-02-05", "2016-02-08", "2016-02-09", "2016-02-10", "2016-02-11", 
"2016-02-12", "2016-02-15", "2016-02-16", "2016-02-17", "2016-02-18", 
"2016-02-19", "2016-02-22", "2016-02-23", "2016-02-24", "2016-02-25", 
"2016-02-26", "2016-02-29", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-03", 
"2016-03-04", "2016-03-07", "2016-03-08", "2016-03-09", "2016-03-10", 
"2016-03-11", "2016-03-14", "2016-03-15", "2016-03-16", "2016-03-17", 
"2016-03-18", "2016-03-21", "2016-03-22", "2016-03-23", "2016-03-24", 
"2016-03-25", "2016-03-28", "2016-03-29", "2016-03-30", "2016-03-31", 
"2016-04-01", "2016-04-04", "2016-04-05", "2016-04-06", "2016-04-07", 
"2016-04-08", "2016-04-11", "2016-04-12", "2016-04-13", "2016-04-14", 
"2016-04-15", "2016-04-18", "2016-04-19", "2016-04-20", "2016-04-21", 
"2016-04-22", "2016-04-25", "2016-04-26", "2016-04-27", "2016-04-28", 
"2016-04-29", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-05", 
"2016-05-06", "2016-05-09", "2016-05-10", "2016-05-11", "2016-05-12", 
"2016-05-13", "2016-05-16", "2016-05-17", "2016-05-18", "2016-05-19", 
"2016-05-20", "2016-05-23", "2016-05-24", "2016-05-25", "2016-05-26", 
"2016-05-27", "2016-05-30", "2016-05-31", "2016-06-01", "2016-06-02", 
"2016-06-03", "2016-06-06", "2016-06-07", "2016-06-08", "2016-06-09", 
"2016-06-10", "2016-06-13", "2016-06-14", "2016-06-15", "2016-06-16", 
"2016-06-17", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-21", "2016-06-22", "2016-06-23", 
"2016-06-24", "2016-06-27", "2016-06-28", "2016-06-29", "2016-06-30", 
"2016-07-01", "2016-07-04", "2016-07-05", "2016-07-06", "2016-07-07", 
"2016-07-08", "2016-07-11", "2016-07-12", "2016-07-13", "2016-07-14", 
"2016-07-15", "2016-07-18", "2016-07-19", "2016-07-20", "2016-07-21", 
"2016-07-22", "2016-07-25", "2016-07-26", "2016-07-27", "2016-07-28", 
"2016-07-29", "2016-08-01", "2016-08-02", "2016-08-03", "2016-08-04", 
"2016-08-05", "2016-08-08", "2016-08-09", "2016-08-10", "2016-08-11", 
"2016-08-12", "2016-08-15", "2016-08-16", "2016-08-17", "2016-08-18", 
"2016-08-19", "2016-08-22", "2016-08-23", "2016-08-24", "2016-08-25", 
"2016-08-26", "2016-08-29", "2016-08-30", "2016-08-31", "2016-09-01", 
"2016-09-02", "2016-09-05", "2016-09-06", "2016-09-07", "2016-09-08", 
"2016-09-09", "2016-09-12", "2016-09-13", "2016-09-14", "2016-09-15", 
"2016-09-16", "2016-09-19", "2016-09-20", "2016-09-21", "2016-09-22", 
"2016-09-23", "2016-09-26", "2016-09-27", "2016-09-28", "2016-09-29", 
"2016-09-30", "2016-10-03", "2016-10-04", "2016-10-05", "2016-10-06", 
"2016-10-07", "2016-10-10", "2016-10-11", "2016-10-12", "2016-10-13", 
"2016-10-14", "2016-10-17", "2016-10-18", "2016-10-19", "2016-10-20", 
"2016-10-21", "2016-10-24", "2016-10-25", "2016-10-26", "2016-10-27", 
"2016-10-28", "2016-10-31", "2016-11-01", "2016-11-02", "2016-11-03", 
"2016-11-04", "2016-11-07", "2016-11-08", "2016-11-09", "2016-11-10", 
"2016-11-11", "2016-11-14", "2016-11-15", "2016-11-16", "2016-11-17", 
"2016-11-18", "2016-11-21", "2016-11-22", "2016-11-23", "2016-11-24", 
"2016-11-25", "2016-11-28", "2016-11-29", "2016-11-30", "2016-12-01", 
"2016-12-02", "2016-12-05", "2016-12-06", "2016-12-07", "2016-12-08", 
"2016-12-09", "2016-12-12", "2016-12-13", "2016-12-14", "2016-12-15", 
"2016-12-16", "2016-12-19", "2016-12-20", "2016-12-21", "2016-12-22", 
"2016-12-23", "2016-12-26", "2016-12-27", "2016-12-28", "2016-12-29", 
"2016-12-30", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05", 
"2017-01-06", "2017-01-09", "2017-01-10", "2017-01-11", "2017-01-12", 
"2017-01-13", "2017-01-16", "2017-01-17", "2017-01-18", "2017-01-19", 
"2017-01-20", "2017-01-23", "2017-01-24", "2017-01-25", "2017-01-26", 
"2017-01-27", "2017-01-30", "2017-01-31", "2017-02-01", "2017-02-02", 
"2017-02-03", "2017-02-06", "2017-02-07", "2017-02-08", "2017-02-09", 
"2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", "2017-02-16", 
"2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", "2017-02-23", 
"2017-02-24", "2017-02-27", "2017-02-28", "2017-03-01", "2017-03-02", 
"2017-03-03", "2017-03-06", "2017-03-07", "2017-03-08", "2017-03-09", 
"2017-03-10", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-14", "2017-03-15", "2017-03-16", 
"2017-03-17", "2017-03-20", "2017-03-21", "2017-03-22", "2017-03-23", 
"2017-03-24", "2017-03-27", "2017-03-28", "2017-03-29", "2017-03-30", 
"2017-03-31", "2017-04-03", "2017-04-04", "2017-04-05", "2017-04-06", 
"2017-04-07", "2017-04-10", "2017-04-11", "2017-04-12", "2017-04-13", 
"2017-04-14", "2017-04-17", "2017-04-18", "2017-04-19", "2017-04-20", 
"2017-04-21", "2017-04-24", "2017-04-25", "2017-04-26", "2017-04-27", 
"2017-04-28", "2017-05-01", "2017-05-02", "2017-05-03", "2017-05-04", 
"2017-05-05", "2017-05-08", "2017-05-09", "2017-05-10", "2017-05-11", 
"2017-05-12", "2017-05-15", "2017-05-16", "2017-05-17", "2017-05-18", 
"2017-05-19", "2017-05-22", "2017-05-23", "2017-05-24", "2017-05-25", 
"2017-05-26", "2017-05-29", "2017-05-30", "2017-05-31", "2017-06-01", 
"2017-06-02", "2017-06-05", "2017-06-06", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-08", 
"2017-06-09", "2017-06-12", "2017-06-13", "2017-06-14", "2017-06-15", 
"2017-06-16", "2017-06-19", "2017-06-20", "2017-06-21", "2017-06-22", 
"2017-06-23", "2017-06-26", "2017-06-27", "2017-06-28", "2017-06-29", 
"2017-06-30", "2017-07-03", "2017-07-04", "2017-07-05", "2017-07-06", 
"2017-07-07", "2017-07-10", "2017-07-11", "2017-07-12", "2017-07-13", 
"2017-07-14", "2017-07-17", "2017-07-18", "2017-07-19", "2017-07-20", 
"2017-07-21", "2017-07-24", "2017-07-25", "2017-07-26", "2017-07-27", 
"2017-07-28", "2017-07-31", "2017-08-01", "2017-08-02", "2017-08-03", 
"2017-08-04", "2017-08-07", "2017-08-08", "2017-08-09", "2017-08-10", 
"2017-08-11", "2017-08-14", "2017-08-15", "2017-08-16", "2017-08-17", 
"2017-08-18", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-22", "2017-08-23", "2017-08-24", 
"2017-08-25", "2017-08-28", "2017-08-29", "2017-08-30", "2017-08-31"
), dcoilwtico = c(NA, 93.14, 92.97, 93.12, 93.2, 93.21, 93.08, 
93.81, 93.6, 94.27, 93.26, 94.28, 95.49, 95.61, NA, 96.09, 95.06, 
95.35, 95.15, 95.95, 97.62, 97.98, 97.65, 97.46, 96.21, 96.68, 
96.44, 95.84, 95.71, 97.01, 97.48, 97.03, 97.3, 95.95, NA, 96.69, 
94.92, 92.79, 93.12, 92.74, 92.63, 92.84, 92.03, 90.71, 90.13, 
90.88, 90.47, 91.53, 92.01, 92.07, 92.44, 92.47, 93.03, 93.49, 
93.71, 92.44, 93.21, 92.46, 93.41, 94.55, 95.99, 96.53, 97.24, 
NA, 97.1, 97.23, 95.02, 93.26, 92.76, 93.36, 94.18, 94.59, 93.44, 
91.23, 88.75, 88.73, 86.65, 87.83, 88.04, 88.81, 89.21, 91.07, 
93.27, 92.63, 94.09, 93.22, 90.74, 93.7, 95.25, 95.8, 95.28, 
96.24, 96.09, 95.81, 94.76, 93.96, 93.95, 94.85, 95.72, 96.29, 
95.55, 93.98, 94.12, 93.84, NA, 94.65, 93.13, 93.57, 91.93, 93.41, 
93.36, 93.66, 94.71, 96.11, 95.82, 95.5, 95.98, 96.66, 97.83, 
97.86, 98.46, 98.24, 94.89, 93.81, 95.07, 95.25, 95.47, 97, 96.36, 
97.94, 99.65, 101.92, NA, 103.09, 103.03, 103.46, 106.41, 104.77, 
105.85, 106.2, 105.88, 106.39, 107.94, 108, 106.61, 107.13, 105.41, 
105.47, 104.76, 104.61, 103.14, 105.1, 107.93, 106.94, 106.61, 
105.32, 104.41, 103.45, 106.04, 106.19, 106.78, 106.89, 107.43, 
107.58, 107.14, 104.9, 103.93, 104.93, 106.48, 105.88, 109.11, 
110.17, 108.51, 107.98, NA, 108.67, 107.29, 108.5, 110.62, 109.62, 
107.48, 107.65, 108.72, 108.31, 106.54, 105.36, 108.23, 106.26, 
104.7, 103.62, 103.22, 102.68, 103.1, 102.86, 102.36, 102.09, 
104.15, 103.29, 103.83, 103.07, 103.54, 101.63, 103.08, 102.17, 
102.46, 101.15, 102.34, 100.72, 100.87, 99.28, 97.63, 96.9, 96.65, 
97.4, 98.74, 98.29, 96.81, 96.29, 94.56, 94.58, 93.4, 94.74, 
94.25, 94.56, 95.13, 93.12, 93.91, 93.76, 93.8, 93.03, 93.35, 
93.34, 95.35, 94.53, 93.86, 93.41, 92.05, NA, 92.55, 93.61, 95.83, 
96.97, 97.14, 97.48, 97.1, 98.32, 97.25, 97.21, 96.27, 97.18, 
96.99, 97.59, 98.4, 99.11, 98.62, 98.87, NA, 99.18, 99.94, 98.9, 
98.17, NA, 95.14, 93.66, 93.12, 93.31, 91.9, 91.36, 92.39, 91.45, 
92.15, 93.78, 93.54, 93.96, NA, 94.51, 96.35, 97.23, 96.66, 95.82, 
97.49, 97.34, 98.25, 97.55, 96.44, 97.24, 97.4, 97.84, 99.98, 
100.12, 99.96, 100.38, 100.27, 100.31, NA, 102.54, 103.46, 103.2, 
102.53, 103.17, 102.2, 102.93, 102.68, 102.88, 105.34, 103.64, 
101.75, 101.82, 102.82, 101.39, 100.29, 98.29, 98.57, 99.23, 
98.43, 100.08, 100.71, 99.68, 99.97, 100.05, 99.66, 100.61, 101.25, 
101.73, 101.57, 99.69, 99.6, 100.29, 101.16, 100.43, 102.57, 
103.55, 103.37, 103.68, 104.05, 103.7, 103.71, 104.33, NA, 104.35, 
101.69, 101.47, 102.2, 100.85, 101.13, 101.56, 100.07, 99.69, 
100.09, 99.74, 99.81, 101.06, 100.52, 100.32, 100.89, 102.01, 
102.63, 101.74, 102.31, 102.95, 102.8, 104.31, 104.03, 105.01, 
NA, 104.78, 103.37, 104.26, 103.4, 103.07, 103.34, 103.27, 103.17, 
103.32, 105.09, 105.02, 105.04, 107.2, 107.49, 107.52, 106.95, 
106.64, 107.08, 107.95, 106.83, 106.64, 107.04, 106.49, 106.46, 
106.07, 106.06, 105.18, 104.76, NA, 104.19, 104.06, 102.93, 103.61, 
101.48, 101.73, 100.56, 101.88, 103.84, 103.83, 105.34, 104.59, 
103.81, 102.76, 105.23, 105.68, 104.91, 104.29, 98.23, 97.86, 
98.26, 97.34, 96.93, 97.34, 97.61, 98.09, 97.36, 97.57, 95.54, 
97.3, 96.44, 94.35, 96.4, 93.97, 93.61, 95.39, 95.78, 95.82, 
96.44, 97.86, NA, 92.92, 95.5, 94.51, 93.32, 92.64, 92.73, 91.71, 
92.89, 92.18, 92.86, 94.91, 94.33, 93.07, 92.43, 91.46, 91.55, 
93.6, 93.59, 95.55, 94.53, 91.17, 90.74, 91.02, 89.76, 90.33, 
88.89, 87.29, 85.76, 85.87, 85.73, 81.72, 81.82, 82.33, 82.8, 
82.76, 83.25, 80.52, 82.81, 81.27, 81.26, 81.36, 82.25, 81.06, 
80.53, 78.77, 77.15, 78.71, 77.87, 78.71, 77.43, 77.85, 77.16, 
74.13, 75.91, 75.64, 74.55, 74.55, 75.63, 76.52, 75.74, 74.04, 
73.7, NA, 65.94, 68.98, 66.99, 67.3, 66.73, 65.89, 63.13, 63.74, 
60.99, 60.01, 57.81, 55.96, 55.97, 56.43, 54.18, 56.91, 55.25, 
56.78, 55.7, NA, 54.59, 53.46, 54.14, 53.45, NA, 52.72, 50.05, 
47.98, 48.69, 48.8, 48.35, 46.06, 45.92, 48.49, 46.37, 48.49, 
NA, 46.79, 47.85, 45.93, 45.26, 44.8, 45.84, 44.08, 44.12, 47.79, 
49.25, 53.04, 48.45, 50.48, 51.66, 52.99, 50.06, 48.8, 51.17, 
52.66, NA, 53.56, 52.13, 51.12, 49.95, 49.56, 48.48, 50.25, 47.65, 
49.84, 49.59, 50.43, 51.53, 50.76, 49.61, 49.95, 48.42, 48.06, 
47.12, 44.88, 43.93, 43.39, 44.63, 44.02, 46, 47.4, 47.03, 48.75, 
51.41, 48.83, 48.66, 47.72, 50.12, 49.13, NA, 52.08, 53.95, 50.44, 
50.79, 51.63, 51.95, 53.3, 56.25, 56.69, 55.71, 56.37, 55.58, 
56.17, 56.59, 55.98, 55.56, 57.05, 58.55, 59.62, 59.1, 58.92, 
60.38, 60.93, 58.99, 59.41, 59.23, 60.72, 60.5, 59.89, 59.73, 
59.44, 57.3, 58.96, 60.18, 58.88, NA, 57.29, 57.51, 57.69, 60.25, 
60.24, 61.3, 59.67, 58, 59.11, 58.15, 60.15, 61.36, 60.74, 59.96, 
59.53, 60.01, 59.89, 60.41, 59.62, 60.01, 61.05, 60.01, 59.59, 
59.41, 58.34, 59.48, 56.94, 56.93, NA, 52.48, 52.33, 51.61, 52.76, 
52.74, 52.19, 53.05, 51.4, 50.9, 50.88, 50.11, 50.59, 49.27, 
48.11, 47.98, 47.17, 47.97, 48.77, 48.53, 47.11, 45.25, 45.75, 
45.13, 44.69, 43.87, 44.94, 43.11, 43.22, 42.27, 42.45, 41.93, 
42.58, 40.75, 41, 40.45, 38.22, 39.15, 38.5, 42.47, 45.29, 49.2, 
45.38, 46.3, 46.75, 46.02, NA, 45.92, 44.13, 45.85, 44.75, 44.07, 
44.58, 47.12, 46.93, 44.71, 46.67, 46.17, 44.53, 44.94, 45.55, 
44.4, 45.24, 45.06, 44.75, 45.54, 46.28, 48.53, 47.86, 49.46, 
49.67, 47.09, 46.7, 46.63, 46.38, 47.3, 45.91, 45.84, 45.22, 
44.9, 43.91, 43.19, 43.21, 45.93, 46.02, 46.6, 46.12, 47.88, 
46.32, 45.27, 44.32, 43.87, 44.23, 42.95, 41.74, 40.69, 41.68, 
40.73, 40.75, 40.55, 39.39, 39.27, 40.89, 41.22, NA, 40.57, 40.43, 
40.58, 39.93, 41.08, 40, 37.64, 37.46, 37.16, 36.76, 35.65, 36.31, 
37.32, 35.55, 34.98, 34.72, 34.55, 36.12, 36.76, 37.62, NA, 36.36, 
37.88, 36.59, 37.13, NA, 36.81, 35.97, 33.97, 33.29, 33.2, 31.42, 
30.42, 30.42, 31.22, 29.45, NA, 28.47, 26.68, 29.55, 32.07, 30.31, 
29.54, 32.32, 33.21, 33.66, 31.62, 29.9, 32.29, 31.63, 30.86, 
29.71, 27.96, 27.54, 26.19, 29.32, NA, 29.05, 30.68, 30.77, 29.59, 
31.37, 31.84, 30.35, 31.4, 31.65, 32.74, 34.39, 34.57, 34.56, 
35.91, 37.9, 36.67, 37.62, 37.77, 38.51, 37.2, 36.32, 38.43, 
40.17, 39.47, 39.91, 41.45, 38.28, 38.14, NA, 37.99, 36.91, 36.91, 
36.94, 35.36, 34.3, 34.52, 37.74, 37.3, 39.74, 40.46, 42.12, 
41.7, 41.45, 40.4, 39.74, 40.88, 42.72, 43.18, 42.76, 41.67, 
42.52, 45.29, 46.03, 45.98, 44.75, 43.65, 43.77, 44.33, 44.58, 
43.45, 44.68, 46.21, 46.64, 46.22, 47.72, 48.29, 48.12, 48.16, 
47.67, 48.12, 48.04, 49.1, 49, 49.36, NA, 49.1, 49.07, 49.14, 
48.69, 49.71, 50.37, 51.23, 50.52, 49.09, 48.89, 48.49, 47.92, 
46.14, 48, 49.4, 48.95, 49.16, 49.34, 46.7, 45.8, 47.93, 49.85, 
48.27, 49.02, NA, 46.73, 47.37, 45.22, 45.37, 44.73, 46.82, 44.87, 
45.64, 45.93, 45.23, 44.64, 44.96, 43.96, 43.41, 42.4, 42.16, 
41.9, 41.13, 41.54, 40.05, 39.5, 40.8, 41.92, 41.83, 43.06, 42.78, 
41.75, 43.51, 44.47, 45.72, 46.57, 46.81, 48.2, 48.48, 46.8, 
47.54, 46.29, 46.97, 47.64, 46.97, 46.32, 44.68, 43.17, 44.39, 
NA, 44.85, 45.47, 47.63, 45.88, 46.28, 44.91, 43.62, 43.85, 43.04, 
43.34, 43.85, 45.33, 46.1, 44.36, 45.6, 44.65, 47.07, 47.72, 
47.72, 48.8, 48.67, 49.75, 50.44, 49.76, 49.76, 50.72, 50.14, 
50.47, 50.35, 49.97, 50.3, 51.59, 50.31, 50.61, 50.18, 49.45, 
48.75, 49.71, 48.72, 46.83, 46.66, 45.32, 44.66, 44.07, 44.88, 
44.96, 45.2, 44.62, 43.39, 43.29, 45.86, 45.56, 45.37, 45.69, 
47.48, 48.07, 46.72, NA, 46.72, 45.66, 45.29, 49.41, 51.08, 51.7, 
51.72, 50.95, 49.85, 50.84, 51.51, 52.74, 52.99, 51.01, 50.9, 
51.93, 52.13, 52.22, 51.44, 51.98, 52.01, NA, 52.82, 54.01, 53.8, 
53.75, NA, 52.36, 53.26, 53.77, 53.98, 51.95, 50.82, 52.19, 53.01, 
52.36, NA, 52.45, 51.12, 51.39, 52.33, 52.77, 52.38, 52.14, 53.24, 
53.18, 52.63, 52.75, 53.9, 53.55, 53.81, 53.01, 52.19, 52.37, 
52.99, 53.84, 52.96, 53.21, 53.11, 53.41, 53.41, NA, 54.02, 53.61, 
54.48, 53.99, 54.04, 54, 53.82, 52.63, 53.33, 53.19, 52.68, 49.83, 
48.75, 48.05, 47.95, 47.24, 48.34, 48.3, 48.34, 47.79, 47.02, 
47.29, 47, 47.3, 47.02, 48.36, 49.47, 50.3, 50.54, 50.25, 50.99, 
51.14, 51.69, 52.25, 53.06, 53.38, 53.12, 53.19, NA, 52.62, 52.46, 
50.49, 50.26, 49.64, 48.9, 49.22, 49.22, 48.96, 49.31, 48.83, 
47.65, 47.79, 45.55, 46.23, 46.46, 45.84, 47.28, 47.81, 47.83, 
48.86, 48.64, 49.04, 49.36, 50.32, 50.81, 51.12, 50.99, 48.57, 
49.58, NA, 49.63, 48.29, 48.32, 47.68, 47.4, 48.13, 45.8, 45.68, 
45.82, 46.1, 46.41, 44.79, 44.47, 44.73, 44.24, 43.34, 42.48, 
42.53, 42.86, 43.24, 44.25, 44.74, 44.88, 46.02, NA, NA, 45.11, 
45.52, 44.25, 44.4, 45.06, 45.48, 46.06, 46.53, 46.02, 46.4, 
47.1, 46.73, 45.78, 46.21, 47.77, 48.58, 49.05, 49.72, 50.21, 
49.19, 49.6, 49.03, 49.57, 49.37, 49.07, 49.59, 48.54, 48.81, 
47.59, 47.57, 46.8, 47.07, 48.59, 47.39, 47.65, 48.45, 47.24, 
47.65, 46.4, 46.46, 45.96, 47.26)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1218L))
```

**Code:**

```
# Tried both of these options, and both don't work
oil_df %>% fill(everything()) %>% fill(everything(), .direction = 'up')
na.locf(na.locf(oil_df), fromLast = TRUE)

# Confirm oil_df has no more missing values
sum(is.na(oil_df))
```

**Output:** Excepted 0

```
> na.locf(na.locf(oil_df), fromLast = TRUE)
> 
> # Confirm oil_df has no more missing values
> sum(is.na(oil_df))
[1] 43
```

Comment: Can you please provide a `dput(oil_df)` ? It's a better format to allow us to reproduce the data.

Comment: @Benson_YoureFired I updated with dput(oil_df) !

Comment: You have to assign the result of `fill()`, like this: `oil_df <- oil_df %>% fill(everything()) %>% fill(everything(), .direction = 'up')`. Then `sum(is.na(oil_df))` is 0 as expected. (You can also use just one `fill()` call with `.direction = "downup"` as in @Benson_YoureFired’s answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the code in the question is that it is calculating a result and then throwing it away and instead of checking the result it is checking the original data frame.  Assign the result of the `na.locf` to a variable and then check that object.  Also note that since there are no NA's on the end we can just use one na.locf if it is ok that the NA's get filled in with the next non-NA.

```
library(zoo)
oil_df2 <- na.locf(oil_df, fromLast = TRUE)
sum(is.na(oil_df2))
## [1] 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `downup` parameter of `fill()` in the `tidyr` package :

> Direction in which to fill missing values. Currently either "down" (the default), "up", "downup" (i.e. first down and then up) or "updown" (first up and then down)

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  value = c(NA,100,runif(4,100,200),NA,runif(3,100,200))
)

   id    value
1   1       NA
2   2 100.0000
3   3 129.3819
4   4 137.7009
5   5 187.6759
6   6 155.0566
7   7       NA
8   8 125.9839
9   9 159.3502
10 10 129.0750
```

```
df <- df %>% 
  fill(value, .direction = "downup")  


df

   id    value
1   1 100.0000
2   2 100.0000
3   3 129.3819
4   4 137.7009
5   5 187.6759
6   6 155.0566
7   7 155.0566
8   8 125.9839
9   9 159.3502
10 10 129.0750
```